# How to set the SharePoint field value dynamically over a button click in edit form using PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-list, edit-form, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a list with edit form has been customized using PowerApps. On edit form opening the fields have been rendering the selected item's respective values. Over the form I have a button which do some concatenation operation and will update the field from which it took the value for concatenate operation.

I tried assigning the value using the field's Default property, but it does not work.

Kindly help me on how to update this field over the PowerApps form using button click.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using Patch function? Check [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-update-text-field-and-Choice-field-on-the-click-of-a/td-p/195192)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1. Declare and initialize a global variable on [OnStart] by clicking [App] in Tree view. For example, for [Title] column something like `Set(varTitle, "")`
2. On the custom Form, set the [Default] property of the field/column to `If(IsBlank(varTitle), Parent.Default, varTitle)`
3. Add two buttons outside the forms - a) Concat b) Clear

Contact button's [OnSelect] expression:

```
Set(varTitle, TitleValue & " TEST");
```

Where *TitleValue* is the name of the data card for Title Value

Clear button's [OnSelect] expression: `Set(varTitle,"")`